# What is the term for a symbol wherein a part of a whole represents the whole?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

A number of symbols exist wherein a part of some whole is used to represent the whole. For example, the atom is often used to represent science, even though it is only one concept in a very broad field. Somewhat more controversially, in one particularly well-known statue, Robert E. Lee is used to represent the American Antebellum South and Civil War, even though he was only one figure in a very broad landscape.

Is there a term for such a symbol, where a part of some whole is used to represent the whole?

Comment: In the written language, it's _synecdoche_. _Icon_ has various senses, one of which is 'a person or thing regarded as a representative symbol' [[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/icon]

Answer (score 2):

**Icon** has various senses, one of which is

> a person or thing regarded as a representative symbol

[[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/icon)]

The 'part of a whole' aspect is quite common, though looser relationships may also occur.

Answer (score 0):

[Synecdoche](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synecdoche)

> a figure of speech by which a part is put for the whole

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers pretty much answer the question, but if you are still in need of another word, you can consider [metonymy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metonymy). A metonym is 
   a figure of speech consisting of the use of the name of one thing for that of another (of which it is associated). It might not necessarily be a subset representing a whole but it's sometimes close enough.

The location of a capital is often used as a metonym for a government or other official institutions. Some examples would `The Hague` for the International Court of Justice or `Wall Street` for the entire U.S. financial and corporate banking sector or `Hollywood` for the entire U.S. film industry or `Bollywood` for the entire Indian film industry or `White House` and `Capitol Hill` for the executive and legislative branches, respectively, of the United States Federal Government.

[Synecdoche](http://synecdoche) and [metalepsis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metalepsis) can be considered as specific types of metonymy.